# ViewBag.Tiltle is not coming instead Layout=null is coming.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have started learning MVC. In the beginning when i was adding a view by default ViewBag.Title="view_name" was coming in that .cshtml page. But today suddenly its showing Layout=null.

I am not getting where something got changed so that it is showing like this.

Comment: While I admit that I'm not familiar with asp.net-mvc, this question is confusing.  Can you try adding a lot of context and maybe an example?  I doubt there is enough information here for anyone to help you.

Comment: when you create your *View* make sure before the view is created that you check the box that says `Use a layout page`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you click *add a view*, and a dialog box appears to see if the checkbox for `Use a Layout Page` is checked.

or you could just simply comment out the `Layout = null` line of code..